# Japan: Civil Code (Act 89 of 1896, Act 44 of 2017): Where are penalty scopes described?

Tags: civil-legal-system, japan, penalty, civil-penalty

Civil Code of Japan is described in Acts 89 of 1896, I am not sure why there is dual reference, probably it was mended in 2017 under Act 44. I.e. the Civil Code of Japan, most part of which is description of contracts, and seller-buyer relations.

The question is, where is the scope of allowed state imposed penalties defined, for the party knowingly breaking the articles of the Code, and refusing to pay out the full compensation?

Such a wonderfully thick book should be worth the paper it is printed on; so where are the iron balls and sharp blades?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Japanese [Civil Code](https://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/en/laws/view/3494/en) generally spells out people's rights which can be enforced in the Courts.

The means of enforcing these legal rights, by obtaining judgments from courts, is normally found in Japan's separate [Code of Civil Procedure](https://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/en/laws/view/2834/en).

Once a court judgment is obtained in a civil lawsuit in Japan, the way that this judgment is enforced is governed, in turn, by Japan's separate [Civil Execution Act](https://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/en/laws/view/70/en). I suspect that there may also be other ways that civil judgments can be enforced set forth in other acts, but do not know that this is the case.

Comment: Oh! Civil Execution Act is the name, that is what I was asking. I need the approxemate scope of penalties on particular articles. I am in the state of private dispute with the seller who seems does not give a damn about the law. Need some persuasive information.

Comment: Hmm. Very complicated Act, hard to understand. May I go a bit deeper into the question? For example, the seller company refuses to repair or replace the delivered product, being informed of the law article requirements, and reluctant to give a counter-argument. In the case of trial, what penalties the Judge may impose? Like stripping of license, inposing a fine, banning the operation in particular region, or forbidding to sell a particular kind of products? Where should I look? In my country of birth, there are a lot of materials available, showing allowed scopes for every kind of misconduct.

Comment: @Asdf "Like stripping of license, inposing a fine, banning the operation in particular region, or forbidding to sell a particular kind of products?" None of these remedies would be available in 95% of civilized countries including Japan. You would sue and get compensatory damages and the costs of collection.

Comment: Thats weird. The U.S. may ban import of particular goods as a result of the legal action, or operation in particular area (btw, exactly the thing which faces Trump). This does not make hte USA non-civilized. There should be just some instrument which should discourage from breaking the law regardless of the size of the damage made. A company with a few billions of worldwide revenue may gulp a compensation of a $1-2K, after incuring $100K of legal outgoings on complainant. But should fear to choke on some regulative response.